# Translate zoom after domain change

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some time-series data whose domain changes: I can take the last 6-months, last year, the last 2 years, and so on. I've created a D3 chart that just displays data.

However, you can also zoom this chart, but when you zoom then change the domain, the zoom "resets" but works again when you click.

When the domain changes, I'd like to keep the current zoom: since it's timeseries data, I'd like it to be in the same place. How can I accomplish this?

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button id="sixmo">Last 6 months</button>
    <button id="oneyear">Last year</button>
    <button id="twoyears">Last 2 years</button>
  </div>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    // Random data
    function randomData() {
      function randn_bm() {
        var u = 0, v = 0;
        while (u === 0) u = Math.random();
        while (v === 0) v = Math.random();
        return Math.sqrt(-2.0 * Math.log(u)) * Math.cos(2.0 * Math.PI * v);
      }
      let days = []
      let endDate = new Date(2020, 1, 0)
      for (var d = new Date(2018, 0, 0); d <= endDate; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
        days.push(new Date(d));
      }

      return days.map(d => ({
        date: d,
        value: randn_bm()
      }))
    }

    // Chart
    const height = 600
    const width = 800
    const margin = { top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 30, left: 40 }

    let x;
    let y;
    const zoomed = (event) => {
      let xz = event.transform.rescaleX(x);
      gX.call(xAxis, xz);
      gLine.selectAll("path")
        .data([data])
        .join("path")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", d3.line()
          .x(d => xz(d.date))
          .y(d => y(d.value)))
    }
    const zoom = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, 32])
      .extent([[margin.left, 0], [width - margin.right, height]])
      .translateExtent([[margin.left, -Infinity], [width - margin.right, Infinity]])
      .on("zoom", zoomed);

    const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);

    svg.call(zoom)

    const gLine = svg.append("g").attr("class", "series").attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    const gX = svg.append("g").attr("class", "x-axis")
    const gY = svg.append("g").attr("class", "y-axis")

    const xAxis = (g, x) => g
      .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0))

    const yAxis = (g, y) => g
      .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
      .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())

    svg.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", margin.left)
      .attr("y", margin.top)
      .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
      .attr("height", height - margin.top - margin.bottom);

    function renderChart(data) {
      x = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))
        .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])

      y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.value)).nice()
        .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])

      gX.call(xAxis, x);

      gY.call(yAxis, y);

      gLine.selectAll("path")
        .data([data])
        .join("path")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", d3.line()
          .x(d => x(d.date))
          .y(d => y(d.value)))
    }

    // Buttons
    const data = randomData()
    const lastDataDate = new Date(2020, 1, 0)
    const buttons = d3.select(".buttons")
      .selectAll("button")
      .data([6, 12, 24])
      .join("button")
      .on("click", (_, months) => {
        const startDate = new Date(lastDataDate)
        startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() - months)
        const filteredData = data.filter(d => d.date > startDate)
        renderChart(filteredData)
      })

    renderChart(data)
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>One way to do this would be by storing the last zoom event in a variable, and, if one exists, then instead of redrawing the axis from scratch, calling `zoomed()` with that last event.</s>

**EDIT**: I now understand your question better. What I did below was as follows:

1. Whenever a button is clicked, get first the zoomed domain `xz`;
2. Then see if we need to clamp it so the domain is a subset of the new data. `xz.domain()` must always fall within `x.domain()`;
3. If that was the case, calculate the scaling factor and the point at the centre of the viewport;
4. Redraw the chart completely;
5. Ask `d3` to scale to the correct ratio, using the previously calculated scale, then ask it to pan to the correct position, using the centre point previously calculated.

Furthermore, I've changed the `y`-domain to always be calculated with the entire data set. This makes sure the line doesn't jump vertically when any of the buttons are pushed.

There is no jumping around the `x`-axis, unless your viewport covers data that is no longer available after you click a button.

**Testcases**

The view should remain the same with all of these:

- Click 'last year', then '2 years';
- Click '2 years', then zoom into range Nov-Jan 2020. Click '6 months';
- Click 'last year', zoom and pan until it covers Feb-Apr 2019. Click '2 years';
- Click '6 months', then 'last year', then '2 years'.

The view should change with all of these:

- Click '2 years', zoom out fully, then '6 months';
- Click '2 years', then zoom into range Feb-Jan 2020. Click '6 months';
- Click 'last year', zoom and pan until it covers Feb-Apr 2019. Click '6 months'.

```js
// Random data
function randomData() {
  function randn_bm() {
    var u = 0,
      v = 0;
    while (u === 0) u = Math.random();
    while (v === 0) v = Math.random();
    return Math.sqrt(-2.0 * Math.log(u)) * Math.cos(2.0 * Math.PI * v);
  }
  let days = []
  let endDate = new Date(2020, 1, 0)
  for (var d = new Date(2018, 0, 0); d <= endDate; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
    days.push(new Date(d));
  }

  return days.map(d => ({
    date: d,
    value: randn_bm()
  }))
}

// Chart
const height = 400
const width = 800
const margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 40
}

let x;
let y;
let xz;
const zoomed = (event) => {
  xz = event.transform.rescaleX(x);
  gX.call(xAxis, xz);
  gLine.selectAll("path")
    .data([data])
    .join("path")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", d3.line()
      .x(d => xz(d.date))
      .y(d => y(d.value)))
}
const zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 32])
  .extent([
    [margin.left, 0],
    [width - margin.right, height]
  ])
  .translateExtent([
    [margin.left, -Infinity],
    [width - margin.right, Infinity]
  ])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);

svg.call(zoom)

const gLine = svg.append("g").attr("class", "series").attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
const gX = svg.append("g").attr("class", "x-axis")
const gY = svg.append("g").attr("class", "y-axis")

const xAxis = (g, x) => g
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0))

const yAxis = (g, y) => g
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
  .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())

svg.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", margin.left)
  .attr("y", margin.top)
  .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
  .attr("height", height - margin.top - margin.bottom);

function renderChart(data) {
  x = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])

  let reScale = false,
    domain,
    centerPoint;
  if(xz !== undefined) {
    domain = xz.domain();
    centerPoint = xz.invert((width - margin.left - margin.right) / 2);

    // If the previous center completely falls out of the current bounds, draw the chart anew.
    if(domain[1] < data[0].date || domain[0] > data[data.length - 1].date) {
      // Nothing
    } else {
      // Else, clip the domain to fit the data.
      if(domain[0] < data[0].date) {
        domain[0] = data[0].date;
      }

      if(domain[1] > data[data.length - 1].date) {
        domain[1] = data[data.length - 1].date;
      }
      
      reScale = true;
    }
  }

  gY.call(yAxis, y);
  gX.call(xAxis, x);

  gLine.selectAll("path")
    .data([data])
    .join("path")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", d3.line()
      .x(d => x(d.date))
      .y(d => y(d.value)))
  
  if(reScale) {
    const scale = (x.domain()[1] - x.domain()[0])/(domain[1] - domain[0]);
    svg.call(zoom.scaleTo, scale)
      .call(zoom.translateTo, centerPoint, 0);
  }
}

// Buttons
const data = randomData()

// To avoid jumpy behaviour, make sure the y-domain is steady
y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.value)).nice()
    .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])

const lastDataDate = new Date(2020, 1, 0)
const buttons = d3.select(".buttons")
  .selectAll("button")
  .data([6, 12, 24])
  .join("button")
  .on("click", (_, months) => {
    const startDate = new Date(lastDataDate)
    startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() - months)
    const filteredData = data.filter(d => d.date > startDate)
    renderChart(filteredData)
  })

renderChart(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="sixmo">Last 6 months</button>
  <button id="oneyear">Last year</button>
  <button id="twoyears">Last 2 years</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I get jumpiness still in your snippet - for example, zoom in with mouse wheel, hit 6 months, then drag the chart (x scale definitely changes on drag here, when only translate should).

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

If you use d3.zoom to zoom/pan, you need to let d3.zoom know when you've manually gone ahead and altered the pan/zoom. It doesn't "know" what sort of tampering you do outside of it. Further, if you are going to update the zoom status of an element so that d3.zoom "knows" of the change, why not use d3.zoom to actually do the zooming and panning too?

In your example, you use the zoom to set the scale of the data, but when you click on the buttons, you set the zoom by merely filtering the data. d3.zoom is none the wiser. That's why the jump occurs when you use a button and then the zoom - the zoom behavior picks up where it was last left.

Lastly, you have written two methods to zoom and pan, when you could just run it all through d3.zoom.

This is not an uncommon problem - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55481420/7106086)'s an example of a the same principle at play.

**Solution**

Only use one method to zoom/pan. This way there is no need to sync the behavior and state of two separate mechanisms for zoom/pan. You can use d3.zoom for both [programmatic zooms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55931250/7106086) and standard zooming quite easily.

You'll find it easiest with a reference scale when dealing with axes and scales - this way zooming is relative to the original zoom state and not the last zoom state (which can cause [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50185040/7106086)). We use the reference scale each zoom event to rescale our working scale. The working scale is passed to the axis generator and used to position the data.

So in your case, our zoom function simply looks like:

```
const zoomed = (event) => {
  xScale.domain(event.transform.rescaleX(xReference).domain());
  draw(data);
}
```

We rescale the xScale each time to reflect the new domain shown by the zoom transform provided by the zoom event.

This works for mouse interaction with no further modification. We can invoke the programmatic zoom with `svg.call(zoom.transform, someZoomTransform)`, all we have to do is calculate the proper transform, using your code as an example this looked something like:

```
    const endDate = lastDataDate;
    const startDate = d3.timeMonth.offset(endDate,-months);

    // k = width of range needed for data set / width of range needed for area of interest         
    const k = (xReference.range()[1] - xReference.range()[0]) / (xReference(endDate) - xReference(startDate))\
    // translate to account for starting point of area of interest.
    const tx = xReference(startDate); 
    
    // let the zoom handle it.
    svg.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
        .scale(k)
        .translate(-tx+margin.left/k, 0) // margin.left/k : account for scale range not starting at 0.
        );
```

Putting that together we get:

```js
const height = 500;
const width = 500;
const margin = { top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 30, left: 40 }

const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width",width)
  .attr("height",height);

var data = randomData();

 
// Set up Scales:
let xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))
  .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])

   // Reference to hold starting version of scale:
const xReference = xScale.copy();

let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.value)).nice()
  .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])

// Set up Zoom:
const zoomed = (event) => {
  xScale.domain(event.transform.rescaleX(xReference).domain());
  draw(data);
}

const zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 32])
  .extent([[margin.left, 0], [width - margin.right, height]])
  .translateExtent([[margin.left, -Infinity], [width - margin.right, Infinity]])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

svg.call(zoom);

 

// Set up axes and miscellania
const gLine = svg.append("g").attr("class", "series").attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
const gX = svg.append("g").attr("class", "x-axis")
const gY = svg.append("g").attr("class", "y-axis")
const xAxis = (g, x) => g
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSizeOuter(0))
  
const yAxis = (g, y) => g
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
  .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
  
svg.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", margin.left)
  .attr("y", margin.top)
  .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
  .attr("height", height - margin.top - margin.bottom);

// Draw:
function draw(data) {
  gX.call(xAxis, xScale);
  gY.call(yAxis, yScale);
  gLine.selectAll("path")
    .data([data])
    .join("path")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", d3.line()
      .x(d => xScale(d.date))
      .y(d => yScale(d.value)))  

}

// Button Behavior
const lastDataDate = new Date(2020, 1, 0)
const buttons = d3.select(".buttons")
  .selectAll("button")
  .data([6, 12, 24])
  .join("button")
  .on("click", (_, months) => {
        const endDate = lastDataDate;
        const startDate = d3.timeMonth.offset(endDate,-months);

        // k = width of range needed for data set / width of range needed for area of interest         
        const k = (xReference.range()[1] - xReference.range()[0]) / (xReference(endDate) - xReference(startDate))
        // translate to account for starting point of area of interest.
        const tx = xReference(startDate); 
        
        // let the zoom handle it.
        svg.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
            .scale(k)
            .translate(-tx+margin.left/k, 0) // account for scale range not starting at 0.
            );
      })

draw(data);


    // Random data
    function randomData() {
      function randn_bm() {
        var u = 0, v = 0;
        while (u === 0) u = Math.random();
        while (v === 0) v = Math.random();
        return Math.sqrt(-2.0 * Math.log(u)) * Math.cos(2.0 * Math.PI * v);
      }
      let days = []
      let endDate = new Date(2020, 1, 0)
      for (var d = new Date(2018, 0, 0); d <= endDate; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
        days.push(new Date(d));
      }

      return days.map(d => ({
        date: d,
        value: randn_bm()
      }))
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="sixmo">Last 6 months</button>
  <button id="oneyear">Last year</button>
  <button id="twoyears">Last 2 years</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Andrew, how are you? Quick question: how would you compute the same for the y domain (as in translateY)? Would the scale be any different? I do the same thing in v3 but the zooming to both domains (x and y) at the same time seems a bit messed up. Can you please help me out here? [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66320735/d3-v3-sync-brush-zoom-and-scroll-zoom)

Comment: Will take a look this weekend - d3v3 zoom was quite different though, will get re-acquainted.